# Tomcat configuration help!

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, webserver

Greetings,

I am having a problem on making this possible.
I am using XAMPP Tomcat 6.02 and Netbeans 6.9.1.
I want these to happen, localhost:8080/myProject/ to localhost/

I have made the port 8080 to port 80 on the conf/server.xml.
I am having a problem on making myProject to ROOT.

Here the steps I've followed.

1. Install XAMPP Tomat 6.0
2. Run it using port 8080
3. Shutdown Tomcat
4. Change port 8080 to port 80 on server.xml
5. Cleared the contest of work directory
6. Created myProject on Netbeans 6.9.1 and set its context path to /ROOT
7. Start XAMPP Tomcat using XAMPP Control Panel
8. Deployed the project on Netbeans 6.9.1 using XAMPP Tomcat as configured server.

And the end of the, I'm getting these error
"The module has not been deployed."

How could I resolve this?

Thanks,
Cyril H.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to move your built application under webapps/foo and configure server.xml with:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps/foo" />
```

This is a static (fixed) approach though and NB redeployment will not work out of the box.

Comment: Using this, what procedure must I avoid then?